# Install node.js npm on Ubuntu 16.04 and Plesk Onyx

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-16.04, plesk

I am following [this guide](http://sscnet.ch/content/install-nodejs-npm-less-ubuntu-plesk) to install npm without erasing Plesk (as I already did) with `sudo apt-get install npm` and most of all the steps seems to be completed but, when I run `npm --version` shows that the command npm was not found:

```
user@server:~$ npm --version
The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install npm
```

If I do that my Plesk will be uninstalled.

This what I get when run `sudo apt-get -s install npm`:

> user@server:~$ sudo apt-get install -s npm
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> The following additional packages will be installed:
>
> gyp libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore libuv1-dev node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-async node-block-stream
>
> node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git
>
> node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits node-ini node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp
>
> node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs node-read node-read-package-json
>
> node-request node-retry node-rimraf node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent node-underscore node-which nodejs-dev
>
> python-pkg-resources
>
> Suggested packages:
>
> javascript-common node-hawk node-aws-sign node-oauth-sign node-http-signature debhelper python-setuptools
>
> Recommended packages:
>
> javascript-common
>
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>
> gyp libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore libuv1-dev node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-async node-block-stream
>
> node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git
>
> node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits node-ini node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp
>
> node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs node-read node-read-package-json
>
> node-request node-retry node-rimraf node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent node-underscore node-which nodejs-dev npm
>
> python-pkg-resources
>
> 0 upgraded, 54 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>
> Inst python-pkg-resources (20.7.0-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
>
> Inst gyp (0.1+20150913git1f374df9-1ubuntu1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> Inst node-sha (1.2.3-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
>
> Inst node-slide (1.1.4-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
>
> Inst npm (3.5.2-0ubuntu4 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
>
> Conf python-pkg-resources (20.7.0-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> Conf node-retry (0.6.0-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
>
> Conf node-sha (1.2.3-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
>
> Conf node-slide (1.1.4-1 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
>
> Conf npm (3.5.2-0ubuntu4 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [all])
>
> N: Ignoring file 'plesk.list.ai_back' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

And after  `curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh`:

> user@server:~$ curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh
>
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>
> 100  6255  100  6255    0     0  12330      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 12337
>
> tar=/bin/tar
>
> version:
>
> tar (GNU tar) 1.28
>
> Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html.
>
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
>
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
>
> Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
>
> install npm@latest
>
> fetching: https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-5.3.0.tgz
>
> added 1 package and removed 1 package in 1.433s
>
> /usr/bin/npm -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
>
> /usr/bin/npx -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
>
> - npm@5.3.0
>
> updated 1 package in 2.473s
>
> It worked

If I run `ls /usr/bin/npm` I get: `/usr/bin/npm` so I could use something like export `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/npm` or something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that ought to work, but `/usr/bin/npm` ought to already be on your path.

Comment: So... what is your advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install native Node.js support in Plesk Installer and you will get npm as

/opt/plesk/node/6/bin/npm

and

/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/npm

Comment: Also I ran this to make it global: `echo 'export PATH=/opt/plesk/node/7/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc`